# Storing and retrieving data from text files in Java

Tags: java, android

What is the most common approach to storing and retreiving data from text files in Java and more specifically in Android projects?

Comment: The question also needs to be in the body. More information please.

Comment: A little bit more effort would be nice. You want us to put effort in answering then put some effort in asking. Some information that could help is: Is the file stored on the SD card or in the data directory of the app?

Comment: You are right. It's too general of a question. I should have been more specific.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't specific to Android, but you'd want to create a [`java.io.File`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html) and perhaps use a [`java.util.Scanner`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) to read it (if it's text). Otherwise you'll create [`java.io.InputStream`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html) and work from that.

Depending on what format you want to use and the nature of the data, you can also use things like [`java.util.Properties`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html), XML, etc.

#### See also

- [Java Tutorial - Essential Classes - Basic I/O](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/io/)

  - [I/O Streams](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/io/streams.html)

    - [Byte streams](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/io/bytestreams.html)
    - [Character streams](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/io/charstreams.html)
    - [Buffered streams](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/io/buffers.html)
    - [Scanning and formatting](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/io/scanfor.html)

#### developer.android.com links

- [`package java.io` at developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/package-summary.html)
- [Developer's guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/index.html)

  - [Application resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/index.html)
  - [Data Storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)

    - Shared Preferences/Internal Storage/External Storage
    - SQLite Databases/Network Connection